# Difference between eager operation and short-circuit operation? (| versus || and & versus &&)

Tags: c#, .net

I am (still) learning C# - and I thought I understood the difference between `&` & `&&` as well as `|` & `||`...

However, after just reading another guide, it is clear I don't get it.

I wrote a little truth table and as I thought, they return the same. From what I have read, using double symbols sounds like a superior solution, but I am a little confused on the difference and was wondering if anyone could please explain/give an example why/when you would use one instead of the other - I tried reading the MSDN example, but it left me more confused than when I started!

[image]

(And, if anyone can come up with a better title, feel free to change it... very awkward to write one!)

Comment: is this about bitwise or conditional operation?

Comment: How about bitwise vs logical operators?

Comment: It is purely about difference between &&/&  and ||/| (which I thought were called, and/bitwise and, and, or/bitwise or), I am still learning and sorry if I use the wrong terminology.

Comment: @Wil, only you know what you want, do you mean bitwise operation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation or conditional operation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(programming)

Comment: I don't understand what is hard about understanding what I want!.... two questions - what is the difference between &/&&, then what is the difference between |/|| - it doesn't matter now, there are many good answers and I will pick one shortly.

Comment: @wil, I will update the title to want i think you want but feel free to do a rollback

Comment: @Fredou - Thanks, and again, as I wrote in the last line, I am not sure what a good title would be as it was complicated!... if you think that is best, I will leave it. Sorry, I know it was awkward.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

& can be used in two different ways: bitwise "and" and logical "and"

The difference between logical & and && is only that in case you use &, the second expression is also evaluated, even if the first expression was already false. This may (for example) be interesting if you want to initialize two variables in the loop:

```
if ((first = (i == 7)) & (second = (j == 10))) { //do something }
```

if you use this syntax, first and second will always have a value, if you use

```
if ((first = (i == 7)) && (second = (j == 10))) { //do something }
```

it may be that only first has a value after the evaluation.

It is the same for | and ||: In case you use |, both of the expressions are always evaluated, if you use || it may be that only the first expression is evaluated, which would be the case if the first expression is true.

In contrast, in other applications && can be the better choice. If myNumber is of type `int?`, you could have something like

```
if (myNumber != null && myNumber.Value == 7)
```

and this would only evaluate `myNumber != null` at first, and it would only evaluate the second expression, if the null check was okay.

```
if (myNumber != null & myNumber.Value == 7)
```

would finish with a NullPointerException during the evaluation of the second expression, if myNumber was null. Therefore, you would use && in this context.

Comment: +1 for a good answer - my comment on this would be however - if you write code that others may have to maintain - do not rely on this as a tool to ensure that side affects happen. Write the code out as explicitly as you can. It will make life easier for anyone who is debugging the code later.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, u are probably right. I will consider that in the future.

Comment: Actually, calling Value on a null nullable results in an InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 5):

you should read this [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: What's that got to do with the question? The question is about bitwise operators.

Comment: bitwise operators don't short circuit

Comment: +1 - I did not know that you could use | and & on booleans to avoid short-circuit evaluation. I will never use that feature in code, but it is good to know.

Comment: if you compare the title and the body of the question, you will notice that they don't match at all

Comment: And in either case (title or question), your answer doesn't answer either.

Comment: @Oded - the difference between the two operators is that & and | will not short circuit when used on boolean operators - that is a huge difference and it is very good to know.

Comment: @Neil - Well and true, and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Oded, it has everything to do with the question

Comment: in the vb.net world, i know this is about c#, it's and/andalso or/orelse, andalso = && and orelse = ||

Answer (score 4):

&& and || are used with booleans. Your output makes sense when using these.

& and | are bitwise operator, meaning they are applied to the operands bit by bit. For example

```
110010010 |
001000100 =
111010110
```

using the same table of your program's output but a bit a time. They are mainly used with integers, not booleans.

Comment: This is not true. In C# you can use `&` and `|` with boolean expressions, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The difference will be less apparent in booleans; bitwise operators are primarily for numbers, whereas logical operators are primarily for booleans. In a bitwise operation (e.g., &), the operation is performed for each bit. In a logical operation (e.g., &&), the operation is performed for the entire result.

For example, the bitwise & of 11 (1011 in binary) and 2 (10 in binary) would be computed as such:

```
  1011
& 0010
______
  0010
```

which is 2.

There is an additional consideration in how the two types of operators are executed. When using a bitwise operator, the expressions on either side of the operator are first executed, and then the operation is performed. When using a logical operator, however, the expression on the left side of the operator is performed first, and the right side may be neglected if it will not change the result.

For example, when I execute `(false expression) && (true expression)`, the true expression is never evaluated. Likewise with `(true expression) || (false expression)`. This is referred to as short-circuit evaluation

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operations are used on integers. You must view the entire integer as 32 individual bits. Most .NET developers rarely use bitwise operations. Check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting tripped up because C# has overloaded `|` and `&`. Used with numeric primitives then they are bitwise operations. Used with booleans then they are just like `||` and `&&` except they don't short circuit.

For example

```
bool Foo() {
    return false;
}

bool Bar() {
     return true;
}

if(Foo() & Bar()) {
     // do something
}

// versus

if(Foo() && Bar()) {
      // do something 2
}
```

In the above example, the first boolean expression will execute both Foo() and Bar(), but in the second one only Foo() will execute.

IMO this is one of the worst decisions the C# team has made. It leads to confusing and occasionally subtle errors.

Comment: Agreed regarding poor design. Nothing jumps out loud enough yellow "I'm eager" vs "I'm short-circuit!" Maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Lazy evaluation is very useful. How else would you handle `if (temp != null && temp.Value == 42)`?

Comment: Plus if Foo and Bar are required to be called because they have some sort of side effects that must be performed, consider refactoring them.

Comment: +1 ok - the example you have written isn't that much different to the MSDN article, however you have explained it **MUCH** better, I couldn't understand why they had a method when I just wanted to understand the difference.... now I do understand!

Comment: @Cameron: Lazy evaluation is great and as far as I know all languages support it. It's the odd choice of adding non short circuiting operators that I disagree with. Granted they are so obscure it's really a non issue, I've never seen them used (purposely) in real code.

Comment: Ah. Well usually non-short circuiting (bitwise) operators are only used on integer types. The most common usage I've seen is on enumeration types as bit flags. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When using booleans there is no difference. The difference becomes more noticable when writing

> 1 & 2 = 3
>
> 1 && 2 = Error // Not 'true' as I wrote before. It would be in C++, but not in C#.

The double operator is a logical operator. It will treat each side as a boolean and returns a boolean that tells you something about these values (operands).

The single operator is a bitwise operator. It takes all bits in each value, performs the boolean logic on those bits, and combines the resulting bits into a new value.

Because a boolean value contains only one bit, the result for boolean operands is the same when using single (bitwise) or double (logical) operator, but since you're (probably) doing some logical operations, it's logical to use the logical operator too. (no pun intended)

Comment: Err 1 && 2 = Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Comment: Yes, oops. C# is a little stricter. :) Other languages will treat the int as boolean, actually translating it to (1 != 0) && (2 != 0). Sorry about that little error. The point remains the same, though. :)

Comment: Well, C# > other languages then. :P

Comment: It certainly is. :p (And not >> )