# need explanation, binary operator | working with boolean types?

Tags: c#, .net, operators

I'm reading an source code, I found a statement like this:

```
if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i]) | GetSpecialChars.Contains(text[i]))
```

Initially,I thought it was typo,instead `||` (or) operator.  But for my surprise, it was compiled. how to it's possible? is | equivalent to || with boolean types?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar questions are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838171/difference-between-eager-operation-and-short-circuit-operation-versu-and) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233835/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-operators).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - | and & operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776007/c-sharp-and-operators) Focus on Eric's top-rated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest that it probably is a typo, though it will still work.

The reason boolean `|` is so rarely seen is that:

1. Much of the time `||` is the only one that is correct. If the expression on the right hand side would throw if the expression on the left-hand was true such as in `x == null || x.Length == 0` which would successfully return true for a null or zero-length string or array while `x == null | x.Length == 0` which would throw an exception for a null string or array as the `Length` property would still be examined.
2. Most of the rest of the time `||` will be faster. It might be nothing but a couple of clock cycles faster (though it could also be more if the expression on the rhs is expensive), but it hardly counts as a premature optimisation that we're all in the habit of using that form. (Just how much effort you put into deciding which goes on the left and which on the right may be another matter).
3. Some constructs that use it by one-line fans are rather unclear as far as readabilty goes.

The example in the question falls under point two. The only effect of `|` rather than `||` here in practice is a few nanoseconds of waste. Not that it matters, but it does lead to `||` being the habit to fall into.

(If on the other hand a property called `GetSpecialChars` or a method called `Contains` has a side-effect that means it has to be called, that property really needs to be renamed to make it clearer!).

About the only time it's useful is either because we really need some side-effect of the right-hand expression to take place, or in the assignment form based on it, `|=`.

In the former case, it's always worth considering an alternative of evaluating both expressions in separate statements and then ORing the result afterwards, to make it clearer that you care about the side-effect as well as the result.

In the latter case, it can make for more readable code, or at least to code that's more readable to some people! But many find it obscures things.

Answer (score 4):

`||` is the short-circuiting version of `|`. In your if statement, the `GetSpecialChars.Contains` method will be executed even if the character is white space, whereas `||` would halt evaluation and not execute the right side.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake, this is a boolean `OR` operator, as opposed to the `OR ELSE` operator represented by `||`. The difference is that the regular `OR` does not [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), while `OR ELSE` does.

In your specific case, `GetSpecialChars.Contains(text[i])` will be called even if `Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i])` returns `true`. If you replace `|` with `||`, this would no longer happen (i.e. `GetSpecialChars.Contains(text[i])` will not get called if `Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i])` is `true`).

Answer (score 0):

The | *operator* in general **has two meanings** as used with integrals and used with booleans. In the first case it calculates the **bit-wise OR** of the *integrals* whereas in the latter case it calculates the **logical OR** when used with *boolean values*.

The second case (the **logical-OR** case) brings another two meanings:

"|" calculates the **logical OR** with the restriction that it evaluates both values i.e. x | y == false if and only if both x and y are false.

"||" does the same thing but only evaluates the second operand if necessary. So in the former example x || y would evaluate to true as soon as x is evaluated to true without looking at y.

You can refer directly to the MSDN documentation for that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.